# c# how to organize dll tools?

Tags: c#, dll, organization

I would like to know which is the best way to organize the dll tools.

For example, I can have a project that has all the class tools the the company has been implement. For example, class to work with strings, class to work with files... and so on. I mean, a generic dll with tools that I can use in many projects. This would be a generic myCompaty.Utils.dll for example.

Other way it to have many dlls, of for each type of work. For example, I could have a myCompany.Utils.Files, other myCompany.Utils.Strings... etc.

With the first option, I would have only one dll, but if two persons need to add or fix something, only  can work one person, because if two persons work at the same time, when one of the person compiles the new dll, the other person loses the work.

If I have many dlls, one for each kind of type of work, then is more difficult that two persons need to modify the same dll, because it's possible that each person is responsible of one of the dlls. However, the problem is that in this way, when I deploy the application, I would have a lot of dlls in the program directory.

So I would like to know which is the best practice when is created dlls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the versioning system, (should be a must when more than **half** developer works on a project), it's really crazy that your organization allows everyone to change the base library (or libraries) on which every other project depends on. This will be evolve in a mess very quickly.

In my shop only one/two people are allowed to change anything there. And these guys are the most skilled and valuable colleagues.

For the subdivision of functionality present in the library I am not concerned with the big one DLL. It's true that I need to redistribute all even when we change a little bit of code (and when your code is mature and well tested this happens very rarely), but keeping track of every dll shipped for this project or for that project outweights the cost of the single one DLL

Comment: I'd argue that's better to allow anyone to change it, but check-ins must be validated by these "high skilled people". Hierarchy isn't agile.

Answer (score 6):

From your question it is clear that you are using no [versioning system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning). Try checking out something like [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) - then, you will have no problems with several people working on same piece of software.

Regarding DLLs - I would go with having multiple DLLs, each only containing a specific type of utility methods. It will make deployment simpler. If you would do the opposite, that is, have a single DLL for all your utility methods, you would need to redeploy it everytime *anything* in it changes - you change the code responsible for working with files, you have to ship the whole DLL that will contain unrelated code, too. Whereas if you'll have multiple DLLs, you only need to redeploy the one that has really changed.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it's going to depend on the number of classes, interfaces and delegates that your library is going to own.

Imagine the case you've 3000 classes in your "Company.Shared.dll" and you're developing a Web application. 600 of 3000 classes are for mobile development. What's the chance of using them in your Web application development? **Zero**.

So why you'd be deploying a 3000-classes-assembly for a  Web application development if you only need Web development-related classes? *Library size is greater than a Web-specific one as first can contain code for a lot of things which wouldn't be working in Web development.*

For that reason you'd have a shared library called **Company.Shared.Web.dll** and a common to all development scenarios called **Company.Shared.dll**.

You can use above logic for other cases and scenarios.